# Access to DOM using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, cheerio, jsdom

i want to access to html file and get an element by id using node.js, this is my html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Diagram </title>

<script>

    function generatePNG (oViewer) {
// some other code
            reader.onloadend = function() {
                base64data = reader.result;
                var image = document.createElement('img');
                image.setAttribute("id", "GraphImage");
                image.src = base64data;
                document.body.appendChild(image);
            }

        }, "image/png", oImageOptions);
        return sResult;

        var sResult = generatePNG (oEditor.viewer);

    });
</script>


</head>

<body >
    <div id="diagramContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to do get  `document.getElementById("GraphImage").src` but with node.js.
I've found that I can use `cheerio` or `jsdom` to acces the `DOM` with node.js, so I've tried this code with `cheerio`:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    $ = cheerio.load('file.html');
```

But I didn't founnd the instruction that allow me to get the `image.src` from the html file, like this instruction: `document.getElementById("GraphImage").src`

Comment: cheerio is a cut down implementation of jQuery not the W3C DOM API. It doesn't have `getElementById`. Go and learn jQuery if you want to use its methods for walking across a DOM.

Comment: @Quentin so i cannot access to DOM using cheerio? what should i do to acces to dom using node.js?

Comment: You can get access to the DOM, just using the jQuery API and not the W3C DOM API. If you want the W3C DOM API then look for a library that implements that.

Answer (score 3):

`cheerio.load()` accepts a string as the argument. By setting: `cheerio.load('file.html')` cheerio will try to implement `DOM` from the string `file.html`. Obviously, that is not what you want.

You should get the `html` data from your file first, then pass it to the `cheerio`. Also as @Quentin metioned, cheerio is a cut down implementation of jQuery, so you should use jQuery selectors to get a ceratin element. For your particular case it would be: `$("#GraphImage")`. Here is how your code should look like:

```
 var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
     $ = cheerio.load('file.html'),
     fs = require('fs');
 fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    } else {
        $ = cheerio.load(html.toString());
        console.log($('#GraphImage').attr('src'));   
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Also, in the html file that you have provided, you are appending some objects to the DOM with the help of javascript. If you want to access them on the server, the javascript should be interpreted there. You can use something like [`phantomjs`](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) to achieve it, but things get much more complicated.

Comment: i'm getting undefined when i execute it

Comment: One, moment. I've missed that it was added by javascript.

Comment: i shouldn't use phantomjs, is there other solution ?

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you need to access dom on the server?

Comment: i need to extract the element "GraphImage" from the DOM, i'm trying with node.js because i can than do the browserify to my node.js script and get a pur javascript code and this is that i want, there is any other solution to access to the dom with javascript?

Comment: And why are you doing all of this? What should be the end result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97875/discussion-between-ameni-and-lazarev-alexandr).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your mixing client side and server side javascript.

but to answer your question you can access the src in the following way:

```
 var src = $('#GraphImage').attr("src");
```

make sure you first load your html file with `fs`

// **EDIT:** Your are getting 'undefined' because the img tag is dynamically generated and not present at the moment you are loading the file with node on the server. That's what I meant your are mixing client code with server side code. 
You might want to grab the diagramContainer `$('#diagramContainer')` and add an image tag inside it and set the source. `$('#diagramContainer').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="theImg.png" />')`

If you have a path you can set it directly if you generate the png on the server an have a binary stream things can get more tricky.

Comment: thisinstruction $('#GraphImage').attr("src") return undefined in my case

Comment: i just begin and i don't understand what do you mean