# node.js regEx that remove a tags

Tags: html, regex, node.js, tags

I need regex that remove all the a tags from html and show the url as text.

for example this text:

```
abc <a href="http://a.com" target="_blank">bbb</a> ccccccc
```

will become:

```
abc bbb http://a.com ccccccc
```

Comment: Why do you "*need*" a regular expression to do this (imperfectly, with edge-cases) when the DOM gives you far more reliability? And why does the `href` (`"http://a.com"`) come between `bbb` and `cccccc`?

Comment: I work on node.js so I dont have dom. I nead to show all the date from html to no-html area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = html.replace(/href="([^"]*)"[^>]*>([^<]*)</g, '>$2 $1<').replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
```

The first `replace` adds the url after the link text. The second `replace` removes all html tags.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [getElementsByTagName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp) for "a" and [getAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) for "href" or has it got to be a RegEx?

Comment: it has got in RegEx, I'ts write in node.js so I don't have dom.

Comment: maybe this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268804/access-to-dom-using-node-js) is helpful.

Comment: I can use also https://www.npmjs.com/package/jQuery but I prefer to use regEx or string manipulation